# Identify Android user account from web server

Tags: android, rest, security, authentication, identification

I have a REST web server that serves the requests from Android devices where I write both server and client codes. Here I want to control and limit user requests based on an account whitelist. For example, I accept all requests for the URL A from any users, but I accept the requests for the URL B only from the user { admin@gmail.com, johndoe@gmail.com }.

Of course, sending a user ID as plain json text is not a desirable solution because the client can be breached. Is there more secure mechanism available in Android; like the device sends a private information of the logged-in account and the server verifies the user identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some type of authentication system, like a simple login, one possible solution could be using a generated token to represent a user session. That way you can control user access without sending sensible information such as the user ID and in case the client is breached, you just revoke that token.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party services.
I recommend Backendless.com
Check it out. Its free, scalable and has a feature of integrating your server tokens into it